# What do all weapon augment modifiers do?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

There seems to be a lot of augments that modify the ammo of the weapon to things like electricity, plasma, plasma seeking, etc.  What exactly are their bonuses and drawbacks?

Comment: I tried the plasma and seeking plasma stuff, and found it much worse than the plain, unmodified versions.

Comment: that a shame, so they do way less damage?

Comment: I'm not sure how the damage changes. But the plasma projectiles are slow, and either unguided and fly in an arc which is hard to aim, or guided, but still pretty slow and not entirely reliable in my experience. My biotic powers are guided anyway, so having a guided weapon is not really a big advantage, and the delayed damage is very annoying.

Comment: There are 8 weapon augments that change the projectile. I think asking for a detailed description of each is too broad for one question.

Comment: I tried the energy beam and seeking plasma augments, and agree that they seemed worse than the regular bullets.

Comment: I don't know, I've kinda got attached to my Valkyrie with plasma charge. It's extremely useful for murdering many enemies in an enclosed space

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This article on GamePedia lists all of the in game text describing each ability](http://masseffectandromeda.gamepedia.com/Augmentation).

These are fairly self explanatory in most cases and it's obvious what the augmentation does from the text on the item however there are a handful of these augments that change the "weapon fire type" - completely changing the handling and impact of the weapon you've augmented and based on your comments on the deleted post I think these are the descriptions you're after.

Essentially in all instances you're trading effective weapon damage for utility, and the damage trade off makes this utility situational at best in my opinion.

**Plasma Charge System** changes your weapon fire type to fire small balls of plasma that arc over distance and explode for a small AOE effect on impact.

This augmentation will reduce single shot damage from a shotgun per hit, relying on their new weapon-fire type to provide a situational use. In this instance, the situational use is the ability to fire over cover (or through cover, since the AOE effect seems to be force damage), hit multiple enemies at once with what would have formally been a single target weapon, shoot the ground, etc.

[image: plasma charge system]

I have found this augmentation especially useful at clearing out corridors on Kett ships, just from spamming blindly around the corner due to the area effect.

**Grenade Launcher** turns each shot fired into a grenade. **Sticky Grenade Launcher** turns each shot into a sticky grenade. Both grenades are equivalent and will overall reduce the damage of the weapon you've put the mod on but the latter will stick to whatever you shoot it at.

These augmentation will reduce single shot damage from a shotgun per hit, relying on their new weapon-fire type to provide a situational use for each augmentation.

**Seeking Plasma System** is the same sort of plasma as in "plasma charge system", but now the bolts will semi-reliably seek targets.

**Beam Emitter** changes your rapid fire weapon to fire a continuous beam, turning it into a damage over time energy weapon. This will increase the weapons damage against armored targets but reduce damage against all other enemy types. Much better used on a weapon with a large clip size.

A single shot weapon will shoot normal projectiles, so if you're going to use this augmentation you'll probably want to pair it up with a rapid fire weapon or a burst weapon fire-type augmentation.

[image: beam emitter]

**Electrical Conduits** will make a rapid fire/burst fire weapon shoot lightning, or a single shot weapon shoot ammunition charged with electricity, with an effect that looks similar to disrupter ammunition. Unlike disrupter ammunition, electrical conduits appears to stun lesser organics (unshielded, unarmored, red health bar only) and have a greater impact on shields.

[image: electrical conduits]

**Ricochet System** gives each projectile fired the chance to ricochet off any flat surface it hits. This mod does not reduce the damage of the weapon.

Comment: So there's no penalty for turning, say, a sniper rifle into electrical conduits?  Also, it seems that i can combine some, such as electrical conduits and plasma charge at the same time.  I wonder what that would do...  Damn i wish this game had a firing range

Comment: lol apparently mixing electricity and plasma is not a good idea, my test black widow does pitiful damage compared to my normal one even at full charge

Comment: Disruptor ammo also stuns lesser organics.

Comment: In summary, it seems like they all reduce the damage and attempt to balance that reduction with special features. Right?

Comment: basically, yes...

Comment: so in other words, they all suck :/

Answer (score -2):

Still can find great utility out of some of these- Try a Widow or Isharay sniper with Heat Sink and Grenade Launcher augments and you'll be very happy with the AOE you can dish out. The best combo I've found is the Soned Assault rifle (basically a Gatling gun) with the Plasma Seeking augment and a Heat sink- it makes the bullets hit for a little less but the seeking augment on a Gatling gun gives you almost 100% accuracy.

Comment: They wanted to know what they all did. Recommending one or two is nice, but isn't what the asker was looking for.