# What happens if you put a beam augment onto a sniper rifle?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

If I were to use the beam emitter augment on a sniper rifle would that raise the damage to a crazy amount or would I have to reload, would it overheat?

Comment: you could try it, then go back to previous save if you don't like it?

Comment: From my experience, it simply doesn't work. I added a beam augement to a valkyrie AR. It still used three-shot bursts, they just looked like lasers. All in all I'm not impressed with the gun projectile augs, every single one I tried made the weapon much worse than it was normally. Biggest offender was a scattershot shotgun with grenade launcher, which then could never ever recharge, giving me 10 shots of weak grenades for the entire mission.

Comment: More specific sub-question of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/304023/108003. Based on the info there, I'd say that you only want to do this on an automatic sniper rifle. It should be stronger against armor, but weaker against other things.

Answer (score 2):

[As mentioned here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/304600/52800), applying the beam emitter augmentation to weapon that isn't fully automatic will not yield the stated effect from the augmentation. You'll need to use an automatic assault rifle (ie: not for example the Mattock or Revenant, which are single shot and double shot weapons respectively) or pistol.

There is a weapon fire type augment to convert a single shot or burst weapon into a rapid fire weapon but this would need to be separately during construction and I haven't tested if this makes the beam emitter augmentation work.

Comment: I've used the beam augmenter on a single-shot weapon before, and it has an effect, just not the one you might anticipate. It shoots single shot little beams, rather than a continuous stream.